# Desabilitar botões

Tags: php, angularjs

Os dois botões "excluir participante" e "encaminhar para autorização" devem ficar desabilitado assim que não houver nenhum participante cadastrado no evento, campos(cpf, nome, situação...etc).

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                value="Autorização"
                title="Encaminhar para Autorização"
                ng-click="encaminharParticipanteAutorizacao(participante.selecionados)">                    
        <span><i class="glyphicon"></i> Encaminhar para Autorização</span>                
    </button>
</div>
```

***ANGULAR***

```
$scope.encaminharParticipanteAutorizacao = function (selecionados)
    {
        if( selecionados === undefined || selecionados === null  ){
            alert('Favor informar pelo menos um participante!');
            return false;
        }

        var bSelected = false;
        angular.forEach(selecionados, function (item) {
            if( item ){
                bSelected = item;
            }
        });

        if(!bSelected){
            alert('Favor informar pelo menos um participante!');
            return false;
        }

        PessoaEventoService.encaminharParticipanteAutorizacao(selecionados)
            .then(function(data){
            })
            .catch(function(err){

        }); 

    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Alguém aqui do stackoverflow pode me ajudar ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a diretiva ng-disabled passando a lista de selecionados ou de participantes existentes.

**No seu exemplo ficaria algo do tipo:**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <button type="button"
                ng-disabled="participante.selecionados.length == 0"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                value="Autorização"
                title="Encaminhar para Autorização"
                ng-click="encaminharParticipanteAutorizacao(participante.selecionados)">                    
        <span><i class="glyphicon"></i> Encaminhar para Autorização</span>                
    </button>
</div>
```

**Ou se você tiver uma lista de participantes:**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
        <button type="button"
                    ng-disabled="listaParticipantes.length == 0"
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    value="Autorização"
                    title="Encaminhar para Autorização"
                    ng-click="encaminharParticipanteAutorizacao(participante.selecionados)">                    
            <span><i class="glyphicon"></i> Encaminhar para Autorização</span>                
        </button>
    </div>
```

Segue um exemplo da propria diretiva **ng-disabled**:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-disabled-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <label>Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"></label><br/>
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
</body>
</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```

Referência:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: Obrigado @Rafael Lucena, deu certo aqui.!!